# Filtering data using multiple field options on button click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have 3 filter options that need to filter data based on the given filter criteria on button click. The first is an input text box that searches username, the second is a date range filter and the third is a dropdown.

E.g If the username field is not empty and the date range filter also has value, but the dropdown value does not change from the default, then the search should be carried out using the username field and date range filter.

So far, what I have implemented only searches for filter option at a time. Therefore if I enter username and a date range, it only returns the result for username since that gets filtered first.

This is what I have so far. I can't seem to find any help. I need assistance, please. Thanks

#### Template

```
<div>
 <div>
  <h5>Username / Email<span></h5>
  <input ng-model="userInput.username">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label>Date range</label>
  <div class="input-group">
   .....
   <input type="text" data-ng-model="userInput.dateRange_start">
   ..........
   .........
  </div>
  <label>to</label> 
  <div class="input-group">
   .....
   <input type="text" data-ng-model="userInput.dateRange_end">
   ..........
   .........
  </div>
 </div>

 <div><h5>Dropdown filter</h5>
  <select ng-model="userInput.dropdown ng-options="x for x in 
  x_items track by x">
  </select>
 </div>
 <button ng-click="searchItem()">Search</button>
</div>

<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Username</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Cars</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in search">
   <td>{{ item.username }}</td>
   <td>{{ item.dateRange }}</td>
   <td>{{ item.cars }}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Controller

```
 $scope.userInput = {
   username: "",
   dateRange_start:"",
   dateRange_end:"",
   dropdown: "Select one"
 }
 $scope.searchItem = function() {
  $scope.allHistory = [];
  $scope.allHistory = data;
    if ($scope.userInput.username !== "") {
       $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.search = $filter("filter")($scope.allHistory, 
          $scope.userInput.username);
       });
    } else if ($scope.userInput.dateRange_start !== "" || 
      $scope.userInput.dateRange_end !== "") {
         $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.search = $filter("dateRangefilter")
            ($scope.allHistory, $scope.userInput.dateRange_start, 
            $scope.userInput.dateRange_end)
          });
     } else if ($scope.userInput.dropdown_selected[0].toLowerCase()  
        !=== "Select one") {
          $scope.search = $filter("filter")($scope.allHistory, 
          $scope.userInput.dropdown_selected[0]);
     } else {
          sweetAlert(
            "Form submission error",
            "Please enter value in at least one of the field below",
            "error"
          );
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running `if...else` so only the first matching filter will do the job. You should change it to chain `if`s.

```
$scope.search = $scope.allHistory;

if (filter 1 has value) {
  $scope.search = $filter(f1)($scope.search, f1_value);
}

if (filter 2 has value) {
  $scope.search = $filter(f2)($scope.search, f2_value);
}
```

Comment: Using chained if's worked fixed the issue. The pipe filtering worked but was not updating the DOM. Thanks @Icycool

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in search|filter:userInput">
   <td>{{item.username}}</td>
   <td>{{item.dateRange}}</td>
   <td>{{item.cars}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yeah. Using chained if's worked. For some reason, the DOM wasn't updating although I was getting the result in my console. Thanks alot for your help. I'm grateful